# Closed Caption 708 for HD Broadcast from Adobe Premiere Pro CC for DMDS

Tags: export, video-processing, closed-captions, adobe-premiere

Is there any resource for a step by step process to export 708 closed captions and 608 captions from Adobe Premiere Pro Creative Cloud for DMDS?

I've set up my sequences, created my captions, and selected embed captions for my mxf export. Once the clip is rendered, I can open the .MXF file and preview with captions, but the results from the DMDS sumbission come back as if there are no captions at all.

I know this is a new feature in Premiere Pro, so fingers crossed someone here can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here's the deal in regards to submission to DMDS.

DMDS does not support 708, yet. So in addition to 708 captions, I ended up adding/including 608 closed-captions for export and submission.

Just like that the submission was accepted.

So just include the 608 and your submission should be fine. If anyone needs assistance with the settings themselves, just message me.